# Trigger.IO header with images questions

Tags: trigger.io

I have been looking into Trigger.IO and am very interested in the headers and tab groups, I noticed they allow images in the headers but its not clear on how the src option works.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to have a dynamic image be in the header or does it have to be packaged with the app itself.

Currently I have an app that, after logging in (depending on the user) a different header image will be loaded, this image is pulling in as base64 and stored in localstorage so I was wondering if this would be possible with the native UI headers, or are they compiled at "build" and therefor need to be part of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. You can dynamically change the current header image using

```
forge.topbar.setTitleImage(image, success, error);
```

where image is the path to the image to be displayed (string) and success/error being callback functions.

Source: [Trigger.io topbar API docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/topbar.html#settitleimage).

Comment: To clarify, this changes the *title* of the topbar to be an image - not the whole topbar itself, which we don't support. Note also, to get a path to your image, use forge.tools.getURL.